# Creating app.min.js file using Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I currently have a Node.js project that has a couple dependencies (request, bluebird, etc.) that I include in my project with RequireJS, such as `var Promise = require('bluebird');`.

I have a Gruntfile that concatenates and uglifies all the files I've created into one big, minified file which works. However, they still have the RequireJS statements. For someone to use my project, they'd need to download my project, run `npm install`, and then they would have all the required dependencies.

I'd like to have a `app.min.js` as a standalone file, with all the required modules concatenated into this file itself, without a user needing to install depencies or import my whole project. Is there a way, using Grunt, that I can dump the source code of each module depencency (and in turn, *their* dependencies) into one concatenated, minified file, along with my code (which I've done this to already).

Answer (score 1):

Try grunt uglify. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Here's a good tutorial as well https://egghead.io/lessons/grunt-minifying-your-output-with-grunt-uglify

Comment: This is useful information, but not quite what I was looking for (I'm already using uglify + concat). I'm hoping to turn such things as `var request = require('request');` into their actual source files, so I can just have one massive minified file with all dependencies included.